# Convergence of $\zeta(k)$ to arbitrary rational number

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, zeta-functions

I have a question about Riemann's hypothesis for $s>1$, we know that $\displaystyle\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{1}{n^s}$ converges, yet $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\zeta(4)$ and so forth are irrational. I wonder that there exists $s>1$ for which $\zeta(s)\in\mathbb{Q}$? Or even more general, is there exists $s>1$ for arbitrary rational number $q$ that $\displaystyle q=\zeta(s)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\zeta$ is continuous on $(1,+\infty)$, strictly decreasing, $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow 1}\zeta(s)=+\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow +\infty}\zeta(s)=1$, thus for all rationnals $q>1$, there exists a unique $s_q>1$ such that $\zeta(s_q)\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: More fun when proving $\zeta(s)$ takes all values of $\Bbb{C}^*$ on $\Re(s) > 1$ (take the right $\sigma$ then choose $N$ large and the right $t$ so that $-\sum_{p\le N}\log(1-p^{-\sigma-it})\approx \log a$)